# categorizing all same categories in a category with total quantity

Tags: java

I have a class named "Expense", Expense has name field and quantity field .and I have a generic list like this:  `List<Expense> expenses`
there are types like food, wear, tax, tutorial and etc in expenses .and they have quantity.
I want to categorize all foods, all wears and etc in a category with total quantity for each category.
How can I do this? please help me and suggest me a method.

Comment: Please see [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the category classes like food, wear, etc., add a static int member that saves the number of objects created. Initialize it 0 in the beginning and increment it every time inside the constructors of the class. In this way whenever a new object is created, the quantity is increased. Here is a part of the code for one of your classes:

```
public class Food{
    private static int quantity = 0;
    public static int getQuantity(){ return quantity;}

    //this is an example for just this constructor, but the same applies for all constructors of your class.
    public Food(){
       quantity++;
       // your code here
    }
}
```